# How to select multiple files at a time with individual close buttons? using jquery.MultiFile.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-multiselect

`enter code here`[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSEUo.png)

how to select multiple file using jquery.MultiFile.js plugin? selecting multiple file a a time with Individual close buttons? 1

$('.multifile').multifile();

Comment: Please provide the code you are working on. Maybe you want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please see attachement....
0
down vote
favorite
enter link description here

Comment: how to select multiple file using jquery.MultiFile.js plugin? selecting multiple file a a time with Individual close buttons? 1